# Android Fail to open the camera. error: Camera new cameraInitNormal:0

Tags: android, camera, compatibility

I got the compatibility issues with camera.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


        int id = CameraHelper.getFrontFacingCameraId();
        Log.d(TAG, "startCamera(): cameraId = " + id);
        camera = Camera.open(id);
```

The code above works fine with Xiaomi Pad(Android 4.4) and Xiaomi Redmi 3S Phone(Android 6.0.1 MMB29M), but fails on Huawei CAM-TL00H phone(Android 6.0) with the error:

```
E/Camera: Camera new cameraInitNormal:0
```

Comment: Did you resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should mention camera permission in android manifest file.

Comment: if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
   {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,      Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
  }else{
  //you camera action as you want
 }

Comment: as you already mention it's working fine less then marshmallow
then you should check permission on run time

Comment: Of course, I grant the camera permission in the running time.